# Use vuejs 3 without router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, single-page-application, router

I created a vuejs3 single page application "WITHOUT" router and routing and also without "url" change ( want to always showing home in address bar)
But need help to do it in a correct way.

**I want to**

1. have a main html page on page have links, buttons or so, that at run
   time page is filed (how???)
2. on start page be filled with the first home page
3. on click of each link or buttons the selected component to be replace in the page

index.html page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Vite + Vue</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

```
main.js
```

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
    import App    from './App.vue'
    import store  from './store'
    import './style.css'
    const app = createApp(App)
    app.use(store)
    app.mount('#app')
```

app.vue file

```
 <template>
        <div>
            <h1>Hello world</h1>
            <button type="button" @click="changeView(0)"> Home 1 </button>
            <button type="button" @click="changeView(1)"> Home 2 </button>
            <button type="button" @click="changeView(2)"> Home 3 </button>
        </div>
        <Suspense v-if="isLoggedIn">
            <template #default>
                <changeViews />
            </template>
            <template #fallback>
                <p>loading...</p>
            </template> 
        </Suspense>
        <changeViews v-if="showIt" />
    </template>
    <script setup>
        import { defineAsyncComponent, ref, markRaw } from 'vue'
        const menus = [
            {
                name: "home"
                ,url: "home"
            },
            {
                name: "about"
                ,url: "about"
            },
            {
                name: "contact"
                ,url: "contact"
            },
        ]
        let showIt = ref(false)
        let changeViews = ref(null)
        changeViews.value = markRaw(defineAsyncComponent((loc) => 
            import(`./components/${menus[0].url}/index.vue`)
        ))
        function changeView(ja){
            showIt.value = false
            if(ja===1) {
                showIt.value = true
                changeViews.value = defineAsyncComponent((loc) => 
                    import(`./components/${menus[ja].url}/index.vue`)
                )
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Pages (home, about, contact) are very simple:

```
<template>
        <h2> Home </h2>
        <div class="card">
            <button type="button" @click="count++">count is {{ count }}</button>
            <button type="button" @click="count++">count is {{ count }}</button>
            <button type="button" @click="count++">count is {{ count }}</button>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script lang="ts" setup>
        import { ref } from 'vue'
        const count = ref(0)
    </script>
```

It is working, but it seems messy and I have no idea how to do it in a good way.

I have searched but every where they talk about how to use routing, while I want to avoid routing and no url-change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use [dynamic components](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components). You can dynamically specify which component to render at a single place.

```html
<template>
  <component :is="currentPage" />
</template>

<script setup>
import PageA from '@/components/PageA.vue'
import PageB from '@/components/PageB.vue'
import PageC from '@/components/PageC.vue'

const currentPage = ref('PageA')

function changeView(page) {
  currentPage.value = page
}
</script>
```

Comment: I also used it this way and it works too. but is it the best way?

Comment: It's definitely better than defining an anonymous async component on each view change. Here you will benefit from caching (not importing twice the same component), avoid re-render with `<keep-alive>` wrapper etc.

Comment: And is this way of handling all app components and views a good way or weird?

Comment: may we make a sample git project?

Comment: As always, Kapcash is on fire on SO!

Comment: @kissu Sure many programmers are on fire, most of the times. But this is an open offer for other who may like to participate, will you?

Comment: @AhmadEbrahimi here, the proposed solution is good and don't need over-engineering IMO. Btw, what is limiting you here? Why do you NOT want to use vue-router? You seem to be working hard to avoid it, is there a specific reason for this?

Comment: @kissu Thanks for your attention, while developing web application where first page starts with login, then all other pages are hidden and it is not necessary to change route and mimic page loading, and many other reasons that cause me try to plan my work as it was in windows application, with out address bar, with one main window(index.html page) and all other lists, forms as child windows ( vuejs components). I really see Routing in user side useless, while all components are downloaded to user browser. Am I WRONG?

Comment: @AhmadEbrahimi a router is not supposed to mimic anything. You can actually skip the transition part entirely (even tho it's always great to have a bit of motion). If you have a dashboard without any public facing endpoints, it's still totally fine to use a router since you can organize yourself better, get something scalable, debuggable, lazy-loadable (hence faster) etc... So yeah, stick to the conventions and use a router, will be less messy and far easier to use. Also, things like Nuxt3 can help you get your router organized by file which is quite handy in your it suits project's needs.

Comment: Agree. A router is just the way to navigate between your app pages. Even if you don't use the url sticked to it. You're kind of re-inventing the wheel here and making your own router in the end.

Comment: @Kapcash : Exactly right, as you mentioned: "it is a way", that root back to web-page era, so may someone help to provide an optimized GitHub sample project, to show the other, and maybe, better way?

Comment: @kissu Disagree, using router is not the only way, and for web application may be even not a good way, due to some side effects. Also organizing components into files and folders is the same as before, the way we do in android or in windows application. I just look for a model that easily and instantly change the "div app" content by injecting component output into main html home page or like this. Any way thanks for your comments

Comment: @AhmadEbrahimi if you don't like the way an SPA is working (using a client-side router) rather than a classic `window.location`, you're maybe not using the proper tool. The "other way" is something that AstroJS may be using. As for the "traditional way" that React, Vue, Angular, Svelte etc...are using, it's a client-side router. If you don't like the idea, feel free to ignore the good practices and replace it in a dirty way with some conditionals or a dynamic component as suggested in the above answer. Changing some content on the page w/ Vue? Done with vue-router. Side effects? I'm all ears.

Comment: Just to clarify I said "it is *the* way", not "a way". That's how modern SPA are meant to be used for routing. As pointed out by @kissu, you might want to take a look to AstroJS, which is using the classic file based routing :)

Comment: @Kapcash I checked Astrojs. I talked about web applications, it talk about website. These are not the same, many can not see differences between them, but they are two things. Any way appreciate your kind attention and help.